# How to set DbParameter value as default. Like we set default in sql insert statement

Tags: c#, .net, system.data, oledbparameter

I know we can set DBnull value to DbParameter like

```
dbParameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Similarly can I set 'default' to DbParameter when I pass parameters to my DbAdapter?

Thanks

Comment: set the DbParameter's value like `default(T)`?

Comment: that will not set default in sql command. It is a default for c# data type.

Comment: Create a method and set it like that.